# Is it possible to ignore pressed key?

Tags: autohotkey

I want to make the following rule: when I press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd>, send <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

I created the following rule:

`^!BS:: Send {ctrl down}{Del}{ctrl up}`

But there is a problem: when <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd> are being sent, <kbd>Alt</kbd> is being pressed.

As a result, the OS process this combination as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Delete</kbd>.

Is it possible to ignore the pressed <kbd>Alt</kbd>?

Comment: I don't know of a way around it. To erase the next word in editors you can use `^!BS::Send ^{Right}^{BS}`.

Answer (score 1):

Best bet:

```
^!BS::
   Keywait Alt
   Send ^{Del}
return
```

ctrl+alt+del is an important interrupt command, so windows tries very hard to prevent scripts and programs from getting into a state where they can't use it. I was unable to make the os logically unpress the alt key, so the best option is to just wait for the alt key to unpress on its own. This means that the hotkey will only activate on release, not on pressing, so you cannot hold ctrl and alt while pressing backspace to delete multiple words, you have to release and press all three keys each time.

Similar functionality:

```
^!BS::Send ^{Right}^{BS}
```

(from comment by user3419297)
The reason I recommend the other option more than this one is that this will not always work the same as ctrl+del. For example, if you are left of a space, ctrl+right will only go to the right of the space, and then the ctrl+backspace will still delete the word to the right of the cursor. Or, if you are in the middle of a word, it will delete the whole word instead of just the letters to the right of your cursor. Also, if you press it repeatedly to delete until the end of a block of text, it will continue deleting the text to the right of the cursor after it removes all the text left of the cursor.

In this case, because you are using ctrl+alt+del, it does not work, but using `send {blind}{Alt up}` followed by whatever else is somewhat more effective at unpressing the alt key, but as in this case, does not always work